# Email doesn't get sent even after changing the email address for error: The target object email address is currently marked as bounced

Tags: email, bounce-management

I am running into an issue when I want to send an email via apex. The problem happens occasionally only with some emails from some domains.

The error in specific reports:

`Messaging.SendEmailError[getMessage=The target object email address is currently marked as bounced.;getStatusCode=EMAIL_ADDRESS_BOUNCED;getTargetObjectId=0030Y00001OnmiuQAB;]`

The actual bounced reason for this specific contact after querying it is:

`554 5.4.7 [internal] exceeded max time without delivery`

## Test 1:

Now, if you hover the triangle you see the explanation shown in the picture. Even if I change the email address(*as the message suggests*) and retry to send the email, I still get the above error.

## Test 2:

When I use the same the email address but in a different contact(*used as `target object id` later on*) the email gets sent out without an error.

## Test 3:

If you use the same email but don't attach a target object id at all to the `Messaging.SingleEmailMessage` instance, the email gets sent without any errors.

Considering **Test 2 & 3**, I am wondering if the message they provide is accurate at all as using the same email address but in a different object, sends the email out. Whereas, changing the email as they suggest still doesn't solve the problem.

[image]